# Broken user input loop

Tags: python

My code breaks when I type `n` in the console instead of looping back to the beginning.

```
from art import logo
from calc_functions import add, subtract, divide, multiply

print(logo)

operations = {
    '+': add,
    '-': subtract,
    '*': multiply,
    '/': divide
}


def calculation():
    num1 = float(input('Enter a number: '))
    for symbol in operations:
        print(symbol)
    loop = True

    while loop:
        symbol1 = input('Choose a calculation: ')
        num2 = float(input('Enter another number.'))
        result = operations[symbol1](num1, num2)
        print(f'{num1} {symbol1} {num2} = {result}')
        reentry = input('Do you wish to continue doing operations? Type "y" or "n".').lower()
        if reentry == 'y':
            num1 = result
        else:
            loop = False

calculation()
```

Comment: It looks like the loop is *supposed* to stop when you type `n`.  What exactly do you mean by "break"?

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided some example input and output, and explain what happens that you don't expect. (That is, why the output is 'broken'.)

Comment: @Simón Rieta Saldaña, were you able to solve your problem yet? Is there anything else in which I can help? Was that answer what you wanted?

Comment: Got it NicKs1, I'm new to this so I forgot to score your answer. Thank you so much ^^

Answer (score 1):

I managed to stop the crashes you reported. I made some changes to your code:

```py
def calculation():
    num1 = float(input('Enter a number: '))
    for symbol in operations:
        print(symbol)

    while True:
        symbol1 = input('Choose a calculation: ')
        num2 = float(input('Enter another number: '))
        result = operations[symbol1](num1, num2)
        print(f'{num1} {symbol1} {num2} = {result}')
        reentry = input('Do you wish to continue doing operations? Type "y" or "n": ').lower()

        while reentry != 'y' and reentry != 'n':
            reentry = input('Do you wish to continue doing operations? Type "y" or "n": ').lower()

        if reentry == 'n':
            break
        else:
            num1 = result

calculation()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a loop over the main function:

```
while True:
    calculation()
```

Comment: This is impossible to break out of.

Comment: Yes, since the author wanted his loop NOT to break after clicking 'n'.